# git clone for shared repository

Tags: git, git-clone

Sometimes it is useful to have a shared repository.
We would initialize a shared repository e.g. via

```sh
git init --shared=0660
```

If the remote already exists we need to initialize, add the remote and pull from it

```sh
git init --shared=0660
git remote add origin <URL>
git pull
```

Is there a quicker way to achieve this using a single step `git clone` command?

Comment: No: the `--shared` option is available only with a manual `git init`.

Comment: The best I can think of is `umask 0007; git clone -c core.sharedRepository=0660 $URL; umask 0077` (I use `umask 0077` so I restore it at the end)

Comment: @phd Can you elaborate a bit in an answer. Especially on your umask usage, and why it is required.

Comment: I set initial `umask 0007` to correspond `sharedRepository=0660`; required because Git doesn't automatically set file attributes on clone. I set final `umask 0077` to correspond my personal preference set in my personal `~/.bash_profile`. For me, it's required. But you may want a different default or no default at all (continue using `umask 0007`) if you gonna work with the cloned repository locally.